# Error in the Soundcloud API: Cannot read property 'substr' of null

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to code a Widget using Soundcloud API (locally).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Soundcloud musics</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Soundcloud musics</h1>
<iframe id="iframe"
    class="iframe"
    width="100%"
    height="465"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="no">
</iframe>
<script src="api.js"></script>
<script>
    var player;
    player = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('iframe'));
    console.debug(player);
    player.load('https://soundcloud.com/somesong', null);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error i got from running this is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null
E @ api.js:204
d @ api.js:328
n.exports.v @ api.js:326
(anonymous function) @ index.html:21
```

I've entered soundcloud's minimized api code into a js beautifier so i can track the error. Here's the code : https://jsfiddle.net/0anL7jfs/

Am i doing something wrong ? It seems that the problem is coming from the SC.Widget() function...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `locally`; the soundcloud api works by streaming tracks from their site.

Comment: @l'L'l i meant that i'm executing this page from my computer, not from a server. I didn't know if it was useful, so i preferred to say it.. but not the right way apparently. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to change a couple of things:

> Define `src` within your iframe with the player widget api url and properties:

```
<iframe id="iframe"
     class="iframe"
     width="100%"
     height="465"
     scrolling="no"
     frameborder="no"
     src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/76067623&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true">
</iframe>
```

> Bind your events with `widget.bind`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var iframeElement = document.getElementById('iframe');
    var widget = SC.Widget(iframeElement);
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        console.log('Ready');
        widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
            widget.getCurrentSound(function (sound) {
                console.log(sound.title);
            });
        });
           widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function () {
               console.log('Finished');
        });
    });
}());
</script>
```

**Example**:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqz1jmzo/ <sub>*( JQuery Version )*</sub>

Comment: The thing is i'd like to access events fired by the widget, etc. I don't want just to play music on my page. And adding Jquery to my page isn't solving anything.

Comment: I'm still not following exactly what you're trying to do; which events are you referring.

Comment: The one when the song is finished, for example. As described here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events

Comment: @I'L'I ok man, it works, thanks a lot. But there's an error in your code, you're calling seekTo() and toggle() outside the ready event's callback. I've corrected this but still, the seekTo() method doesn't work...

Comment: Great, glad the code worked... about the seek - yeah I was trying some things out and forgot to remove that - thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: It didn't work because it was intended for using a custom button to toggle the playback. If you click the button it pauses it, and when you click it again the method resumes the track from where it left off... Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/okw7xa0w/ (it's a bit laggy running it on jsfiddle)

Comment: For the record, using id 0 shows the SoundCloud logo and nothing else: `src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/0"`